# Router navigate on Ionic with animation blinking on ios using angular animations

Tags: angular, ionic4

I am setting page transitions between two pages on Ionic (v4) with @angular/animations and it all works great on chrome but not on safari.

On a simple app only with two pages (eagerly loaded) I still have the problem, independent of the property that I try to animate. The blinking only goes away if I create an empty animation, but it is not the goal. Also, I am using eager loading.

animations.ts

```
 export const fadeIn =
    trigger('fadeIn', [
      state('entering', style({ //styles to be transitioned
        opacity: 1,

      })),
      transition("* => entering", [ //this styles will enter before the animation starts
          style({
            opacity: 0,
            display: block
          }),
          animate('500ms')
      ]),

      state('leaving', style({  //this styles will enter when the animation ends
        opacity: 0,
        display: none
      })),
      transition("* => leaving", [ //styles to be transitioned
        animate('220ms', style({
          opacity: 0,
        }))
      ]),
```

page1.ts

```
... 
anim = ''
import { fadeIn } from '../animations/animations'
import { Router } from '@angular/router'
...
@Component({
  selector: 'page-1',
  templateUrl: './page1.html',
  styleUrls: ['./page1.scss'],
  animations: [ fadeIn ]
})

constructor(private router: Router){ }

ionViewWillEnter(){
  this.anim = 'entering'
}

nextPage(){
  this.router.navigate(['/page2'])
}
```

page2.ts

```
... 
import { fadeIn } from '../animations/animations'
import { Router } from '@angular/router'
...
anim = ''
@Component({
  selector: 'page-2',
  templateUrl: './page2.html',
  styleUrls: ['./page2.scss'],
  animations: [ fadeIn ]
})

constructor(private router: Router){ }

ionViewWillEnter(){
  this.anim = 'entering'
}

previousPage(){
  this.anim = 'leaving'
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.router.navigate(['/page1'])
  }, 200) //220 is the actual time to the transition end, but 200 to make sure that the blinking is not by an 'empty animation state'
}
```

page1.html

```html
<ion-content [@fadeIn]='anim'>
  <h1> This is the first page!
</ion-content>
```

page2.html

```html
<ion-content [@fadeIn]='anim'>
  <h1> This is the second page!
</ion-content>
```

page1.scss and page2.scss

```css
ion-content{
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

global.scss

```css
@import "~@ionic/angular/css/core.css";
html > body > app-root > ion-app > ion-router-outlet > .ion-page-hidden {
  display: flex !important;
}
...
```

To illustrate the issue better I recorded it in slow motion and uploaded to [Giphy](https://giphy.com/gifs/Zb6YrET2x2jaRy2bZm)

I expected the same result that I had on chrome on safari, which is the use of this animation structure without blinking between pages

Comment: What happens if you apply the animation (and the custom css rules) not to the `ion-content` but to an inner `div` for example? I think that your animation may be conflicting with the animation Ionic uses when navigating from one page to another...

Comment: Inside ion-content the animation works well. Your guess is right, I think, but you think that I can override the default animation? I already tried to put animated=false on the ion-router-outlet.

Comment: Doing `<ion-router-outlet main animated="false"></ion-router-outlet>` didn't work?

Comment: Yes, it didn't work

Comment: What version of Ionic are you using? Would you mind updating to `4.4`?

Comment: It didn't work too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll add this answer since it's a bit long to be a comment. As we discussed in the comments, the issue is because your animation is conflicting with the default **[iOS page transition animation](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/core/src/utils/transition/ios.transition.ts)**

The recommended way to fix this issue would be to **create your own page transition animation** as you can see **[in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56183114/3915438)**. Doing that would apply your custom animation overriding the default "animation" of all `ion-nav` and `ion-router-outlet` **across the whole application**.

If for some reason you just want to use Angular animations on each and every page - like you're doing in your code by using something like

```
<ion-content [@fadeIn]='anim'> 
  ...
</ion-content>
```

you can disable Ionic's default page transition animations via **[the Config](https://ionicframework.com/docs/utilities/config#config-options)**:

> **animated**:  boolean | If true, Ionic will enable all animations and transitions across the app.

```
@NgModule({
  // ...
  imports: [
    // ...
    IonicModule.forRoot({
      animated: false
    }),
  ],
  //...
```

Comment: I think you are right about the motive of the glitch even though it remains after changing the animated property on the app.module. Since I am struggling with this for days and another ways of animate are available I will grant the correct answer. Thanks for your help.