# Component within page not animating on navigate for iOS

Tags: angular, ionic4

When navigating to a new screen by calling `NavController.navigateForward('/url')` you get a free native animation which slides the screen in to view. This works as expected unless I use a component within a page component. When I do that, everything animates as expected except the component within the page.

When the following page is navigated to the content and title all slide into view as expected.

```
<ion-header>
    <h1>The Title</h1>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
    Some content...
</ion-content>
```

However, if I extract the `h1` tag to a component only the "Some content..." slides into view. "The Title" is displayed with no animation.

```
<ion-header>
    <app-my-component>The Title</app-my-component>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
    Some content...
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why that's happening is because Ionic expects the `ion-title` to be in a certain place for it to be animated. You can see that by inspecting the the **[source code of the iOS page transition](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/core/src/utils/transition/ios.transition.ts)**.

As you can see **[here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/core/src/utils/transition/ios.transition.ts#L44)** Ionic gets the entering `ion-toolbar` like this:

```
const enteringToolBarEls = enteringEl.querySelectorAll(':scope > ion-header > ion-toolbar');
```

And **[here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/core/src/utils/transition/ios.transition.ts#L74)** it gets the `ion-title` like this:

```
enteringTitle.addElement(enteringToolBarEl.querySelector('ion-title'));
```

That won't work since the structure of the HTML code will be different if you use a custom component in your `ion-header`:

```
ion-header > your-component > ion-toolbar
```

It's recommended not to use a custom component in the `ion-header` because Ionic expects it to be in a specific way in order to animate it properly.

---

That being said, if you really need to use a custom component there, you can crate your own custom page transition like this:

1. Create a new file `myAwesomeTransitionAnimation.ts` with the content of the  **[source code of the iOS page transition](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/core/src/utils/transition/ios.transition.ts)**.
2. Edit the code to make the transition work with your specific HTML structure
3. Edit the `app.module.ts` file to use that transition instead of the default:

```
imports: [
    ...
    IonicModule.forRoot({  
      navAnimation: myAwesomeTransitionAnimation,
    }), 
  ],
```

Please keep in mind that doing so would override the default "animation" of all `ion-nav` and `ion-router-outlet` **across the whole application**.

If you just want to override it for iOS (using the default for Android), please take a look at **[this comment](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/16829#issuecomment-455508232)**:

```
let ionic = [
  IonicModule.forRoot()
];

const platform = new Platform();

if (platform.is('ios')) {
  ionic = [
    IonicModule.forRoot({
      navAnimation: myAwesomeTransitionAnimation,
    })
  ]
}
```

And in module imports:

```
imports: [ ...ionic, ]
```

Comment: Thank you for providing such a well articulated answer. Newbie alert; I just started working with ionic and angular a couple weeks ago. When I attempted to trace back through the SC starting at navigateForward I did not land in iosTransitionAnimation as you did which led to you being able to identify the root of the problem. Assuming I missing some fundamentals and need to read up on something...how did you go about tracing back to iosTransitionAnimation?

Comment: @Craig Glad to hear that it helped :) Well actually two years ago I was investigating [this issue using Ionic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936198/ionic-2-global-navbar-for-the-app/37808988#37808988) when Mark Hartington (from Ionic team) wrote a comment pointing us in the right direction. Since that day I really enjoy reading the source code of Ionic to know how things work behind the scenes and to learn how to create new features following their recommended practices.

Comment: Thanks! Addtion to, posting(https://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20200501-CustomizingPageTransitionsInIonic5.html) was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is quite old but I'd like to share another simple and really useful solution I found specifically using an Angular feature: "ViewContainerRef" (credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56887630) for the approach).

In the page `.html`:

```
<ion-header>
  <my-toolbar></my-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

`.html`:

```
<ng-template #template>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Example</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ng-template>
```

`.ts`:

```
@ViewChild('template', { static: true }) template;


constructor(
  private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef
) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.template);
}
```

This allows the ion-toolbar to be embedded directly in the ion-header instead of wrapped by the obscuring my-toolbar element, and avoid having to fix the transition issue at all.

Hope this helps anyone else stumbling across this in 2023!