# How to debug Ionic iOS swipe gesture issues

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic4, hammer.js

I am dealing with a weird bug on Ionic's iOS native build where I sometimes cannot swipe back or switch tabs once I transition to a new page using `router.navigateByURL(...)`, and trying to debug this issue has been troublesome since I can't "see" how the gestures are handled. Does anyone know where I should be looking in the code for handling transition gestures?

Here's a video demo of the problem: https://streamable.com/hk9c0

In the video, you can see me:

1. Swiping down to refresh using the `ion-refresher` element and you can see the page beneath (already entered a bug report for that part: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/18284 )
2. Trying to tap the back arrow in the left corner
3. Attempting to swipe left to right to go back a page (hard to show that one)
4. Tapping the bottom tabs to transition to new tab, at one point, I tap on a tab that has an `ion-fab` element which appears in the bottom right because its `z-index` is higher than the "stuck" page.

Currently the best I've been able to do is by looking at the css classes that are added to the pages, but it's not much use....

[image]

Where `app-release` is the page you can see in the video and `app-home` is the page underneath the stack. It's my understanding that Ionic uses `hammer.js`for gestures, so I added it as a tag, please correct me if I am wrong. I cannot, for the life of me, recreate this bug consistently, but will often trigger 1 out of 50 tries.

I've been digging through the `utils` in Ionic Core to see where elements are being added and removed, with no luck.

I created a bug request for this here as well: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/18305

Answer (score 0):

Are you using @angular/animations to make the transitions between the pages? I had some issues like yours, as you can see in my question.
[Router navigate on Ionic with animation blinking on ios using angular animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56151681/router-navigate-on-ionic-with-animation-blinking-on-ios-using-angular-animations)

If I am right about the use of @angualar/animations I suggest to use a custom animation of the Ionic itself, and not te angular's. You can see an working example here of its use here:
https://github.com/mhartington/ionic4-custom-animation

Since I have less tem 50 rep I cant comment so I had to post this anwser not knowing if it was really your case. Hope it helps.